# What is the difference between "algo" and "alguna cosa"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

What is the difference between "algo" and "alguna cosa", since they both mean "something"? How do you know which one to use?

> *¿Estás mirando algo en la tele?* Are you watching something on TV?
>
> *¿Es alguna cosa de comer?* Is it something to eat?
>
> *¿Ha visto alguna cosa?* Have you seen something?
>
> *Hay algunas cosas que no te he contado.* There are some things I haven't told you.

In addition, when should *de* follow *algo*?

> *Te compré algo de comer.* I bought you something to eat.

Comment: Welcome to the site... While someone has the time for a full answer _Algo_ is an undefined pronoun _alguno/alguna_ is an adjective and they play different roles on the sentence.

Comment: Yes, welcome to the site. As @DGaleano mentioned, someone who has time for a more thorough answer (or more knowledge about the Spanish language than I do) may, in fact, be working on one as I type this. In the meantime, I found this link here from the StackExchange for English Language Learners. I don't know if the same thing is happening with "algo" and "alguna cosa," but stranger things have happened. The thread is titled, [**"What's the difference between something and some thing?"**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119446/whats-the-difference-between-something-and-some-thing)  HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"algo" is much more usual than "alguna cosa" for at least the following reasons:

- "algo" is shorter
- "alguna cosa" tends to be more heavy-handed
- "algo" can refer to something concrete or abstract. The use of the noun "cosa" may suggest the existence of something physical.

Therefore:

We do say: *¿Estás mirando **algo** en la tele?*, but saying *¿Estás mirando **alguna cosa** en la tele?* would be unnecessarily long as well as rather awkward.

The sentence *¿Es alguna cosa de comer?* sounds a bit off, especially because of the preposition "de": "para comer" would be more idiomatic. Once again, *¿Es **algo** para comer?* is both shorter and better. Similarly, I'd say *Te compré algo para comer.*

The question *¿Ha visto alguna cosa?* sounds incomplete. It'd be more usual to find a relative clause or an adjectival structure after "cosa": *¿Ha visto alguna cosa (algo) en especial / alguna cosa (algo) que le llame la atención?* I prefer "algo" in both cases, unless we need to emphasize the physical nature of the thing in question.

In the case of *Hay algunas cosas que no te he contado*, "algo" is not possible because it lacks the plural sense of "alguna**s** cosa**s**".

Comment: Gustavson, if my edit (heavy-handed) isn't helpful don't hesitate to roll it back.

Comment: But "Hay algo que no te he contado" does work as a sentence -- which one would be chosen just depends on whether it's multiple things or not.  Other than that I find this a wow of an answer, some subtleties here with clear, concise explanations.

Comment: @aparente001 Of course it works, but as you say "algunas cosas" suggests a plurality absent in "algo".